# Maven dependencies for IBM Websphere packages

Tags: java, maven, websphere-8

I'm trying to convert a "classic" JAVA EE project, using IBM websphere 8.0.0.5, into a maven multi module project and facing issues with the IBM dependecies.

We use IBM classes from the following packages:

- com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans
- com.ibm.websphere.scheduler
- com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm
- com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans
- com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool

To get my local project to be compiled I downloaded the was.installer-8.0.0.pm from [IBM](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/com/ibm/tools/target/was.installer/8.0.0/) and installed it to my maven using

```
mvn install -f "was.installer-8.0.0.pom" -D serverInstallationFolder="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer"
```

This step was successfull according to command line output.

I then added the following dependencies to my project as described from IBM:

In parent:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
 <artifactId>was</artifactId>
 <version>8.0.0</version>
 <type>pom</type>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

In module:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
   <artifactId>was</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

But I still can't compile my project as the IBM packages are not found.

Can anyone help me to find and correct a mistake I made?

**Edit**

After following BevynQ tip from the comments I copied the "was_public.jar" to "was_public-8.0.0.jar" (described at [IBM here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/install_server_apis.htm)) and added it to my repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\dev\was_public-8.0.0.jar" -DpomFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\dev\was_public-8.0.0.pom"
```

I then changed the dependencies to:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver</groupId>
 <artifactId>was_public</artifactId>
 <version>8.0.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>was</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

This helped to get the compiling errors for the imports to `com.ibm.websphere` done.

What I now have still open is the packages `com.ibm.ws.*` package. Anyone have an idea?

**Edit 2**
I added the following dependency and then I was rid of the `com.ibm.ws.*` import errors.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But it still does not compile as now indirectly references can not be found (in my case `commonj.work.WorkManager`). It seems I need to add further .jars for every single thing. Isn't there an easier way to provide all websphere jars at once as descirbe in the above linked tutorial with the `com.ibm.tools`dependency (which do not work)?

Comment: I don't think that will work. You want to install the required libraries to your local store. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html. The POM is not enough

Comment: I've edited my question after trying your advise and I could get the `com.ibm.websphere` packages to be compiled, but still missing several of the `com.ibm.ws` ones. Anyone knows how to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution so I solved my dependency problems:

1. I configured the company repository manager (nexus) as a mirror. In this nexus all ibm packages are present. As you can think that solved the main problem.
2. I then added the following dependencies according to common maven style:

Dependencies in `pom.xml` (version numbers extracted to properties):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</artifactId>
  <version>${ibm.ws.runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.ws.prereq</groupId>
  <artifactId>commonj-twm</artifactId>
  <version>${ibm.ws.prereq.commonj-twm.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Sorry I can't provide a "nice" solution that's useable by all people but the answer from *njr* and the comment from *BevynQ* helped at lot to get clearer with the problem and helped to solve the problem in a "more manual" way by copying the needed jars by hand.

Comment: How is Nexus resolving the IBM packages? Were they added there manually (e.g. third party repository)?

Answer (score 3):

In general, `com.ibm.websphere` are public API for use by applications (this is true of the packages you listed above) which is consistent with these being in `was_public.jar`

However, `com.ibm.ws` package is generally product internals.  May I ask what interface methods you are using from the `com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans` package?  Maybe there is a public API alternative.

Regarding `commonj.work`, the only place I can find this in the WebSphere Application Server product image is  `WAS/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.commonj-twm.jar`  so it looks like you will need to use that to compile against.

Comment: Users should not access the content of WAS_HOME/plugins/ directly, so this should probably be considered a product issue.  APARs have been taken for other APIs that were not available in WAS_HOME/dev/ (e.g., http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM85738).

Comment: For example we use the  `WorkManagerImpl` from the `com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans` package. I'm not sure if I'm "allowed" to change the libraries as it is an productive module and the migration for maven and CI is (at current stage) a first step to gather experience with maven and to be able to do CI in the future. Thank you for the hint in which jar the `commonj` files are. Yesterday I got notice of a company wide nexus where the ibm files are in so that's a way I try now. But I will keep your answer in mind and will respont to it later again.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue as I tried to build a project using Maven version 3.3.9, running on Java version 1.8.0_101, as depicted in the screenshot:

[image]

This is how I resolved it: **Step 1.** Download the commonj.jar from [here](http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.oracle/oc4j/11/jars/commonj.jar.html).
**Step 2.** Determine which JDK your Maven is using by typing `mvn -version` in the command prompt. [image]

**Step 3.** Go to that directory and place the `commonj.jar` file there in the `jre/lib/ext` directory, as shown below. Now your project should build in maven without any issues.

[image]